# How to list losses of a model in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I am in the middle of debugging a combination of the models in Keras and I wanted to verify loss functions for different models. For example to see if model1 has really the losses as ['mae','hinge'].

I know `model.summary()` does not help, as it does not provide the model losses.

Is there a way to list the loss(es) for each model in Keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like this.

```
>>> model.loss
'categorical_crossentropy'
>>> model.metrics
['accuracy']
```

Comment: REPL auto-completion is your friend. Or use the dir() method. Sometimes, it is easier to explore the methods of a class using these ways.

Comment: Or use `vars(your_object)` to avoid getting a lot of magic methods, if appropriate.